# How to change a value of table in triggers

Tags: sql-server, triggers

If I want to write a trigger, that if something has changed and does not have the right value, It automatically becomes something else?!

for example I have a table of student numbers and grades. I want to write a trigger that if any number entries any time in the table was less than zero, It becomes automatically zero.

Comment: Why not add a check constraint and so throw an error on invalid input rather than silently "fixing" it and masking the problem? If someone enters `-80` how do you know it wasn't supposed to be `80`?

Comment: I dont know how to code this, drop the value from table and then insert it?! Can you tell me this with a simple code?! thanks

Comment: I agree with @Martin - *fail early, fail loud*

Answer (score 1):

I would prevent invalid values from being saved via your application.

One way in your database would be adding a constraint on your values.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_myTable_grade CHECK (grade BETWEEN 0 AND 100)
```

This would fail INSERTs or UPDATEs with invalid values, which is better than assuming -80 should = 0